# The Arduino robot tutorials describe a cord comming with the official robot, now I'm confused

Tags: hardware, robotics

I recently got the Arduino Robot and have been looking at the examples for the RobotLibrary. As I looked, I found something quite confusing (for me at least), a few of them describe connecting a sensor (like an [IR sensor](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/RobotRemoteControl) or [Ultrasonic sensor](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/RobotRunawayRobot)) to a port with a cable that was provided with the robot. But I never received a cable. Which got me to question, what type of cable is this, because it is not the same cable you would use on an UNO, at least not according to the pictures. So does anyone know what type of cables these are and/or where I can get them? Thanks :smiley-mr-green:

Here are the pictures btw:

[image]

And the next one:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Usually, Arduino gives you the minimal board and sends you on your way. Reading over the instructions, I think they mean a cable that would have come with the IR sensor. That three-tone cord you see in the pictures are actually just three wires. You connect them as described if they came with the sensors. More likely, if they did not, you can use your own wires to connect these. Just be sure that you understand which is the ground (GND), power (+5V or some other +V), and signal. Usually, ground is denoted by the darkest color: black or brown; power is usually red, and signals can be any light color. USUALLY (READ about your device before you plug it in) ground and power are side-by-side for IR sensors, and signal is on the outside. Take a few minutes to Google up your device before plugging it in if you don't have documentation.

Good Luck!